# What is a comma splice?

Tags: punctuation, commas, comma-splices

Is this a comma splice?   What makes a sentence a comma splice?

> Being left at the altar on her wedding
>   day, Pamela became furious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was just a [post today on Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2563) about constructions like this, known as *absolutives*. In it, Mark Liberman quotes from the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language:

pages 1265-6 of CGEL, where the followed two examples are given:

> *His hands gripping the door*, he let out a volley of curses.
> *This done*, she walked off without another word.
>
> ...
> The [italicized] non-finites are supplements with the main clause as anchor. [The examples shown] contain a subject, and belong to what is known as the absolute construction, one which is subordinate in form but with no syntactic link to the main clause. […]
>
> In [none of these examples] is there any explicit indication of the semantic relation between the supplement and the anchor. This has to be inferred from the content of the clauses and/or the context.

A *comma splice*, on the other hand, is when two sentences are connected with a comma instead of a period.

Answer (score 8):

I would say no, because "Being left at the altar on her wedding day" isn't an independent clause.

It would be considered a comma splice if you phrased it this way:

> Pamela was left at the altar on her
>   wedding day, she was furious.

Answer (score 0):

> Being left at the altar on her wedding day, Pamela became furious.

The sentence above starts with a participial phrase; in that case, it's correct to use the comma (which is the only way to separate phrases, in cases such as these).

A comma splice would occur in a sentence like the following.

> The Taylors won a new swimming pool, however, no one in the family knew how to swim.

Instead of the comma before *however*, there should be a semicolon or a period.

> The Taylors won a new swimming pool; however, no one in the family knew how to swim.

Comment: Replace the "however," with "but" and you can keep the comma.

Comment: @Martha - in that case you'd need to lose the second comma; "x, but, y" is horrifying.  And incorrect.

Comment: I feel like the correct sentence would also include the word *swi**m*** and not the non-word *swi**n***. ;)

Comment: Why would you use a semi-colon rather than a period?

Comment: @kojow7 It is a matter of preferences. You can use either one or the other.